# SQlite "no such table" after updating application

Tags: android, sqlite

I updated my application today and started seeing the following in crashlitics:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: LESSONATTACHMENT (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT _THUMB_PATH FROM LESSONATTACHMENT WHERE _id = 2
```

I create a new table inside my `SQLiteOpenHelper`, it was not in the application before I update.

This is how I created the table:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LESSON_ATTACHMENTS);
}
```

Should I instead place it in `OnUpgrade`? Like this:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LESSON_ATTACHMENTS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to increase your Database Version and create the new Table in  onUpgrade and Maybe delete the old Table.

Your Database is created only once. Upgrades are done in the onUpgrade function

You can also delete the Database and it will be created new with the new Table, but it depends if you are able to do this at the Moment.

for example this Code will upgrade your Database up to the current Version

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    switch(oldVersion){
        case 1:
            //Changes between version 1 and 2
        case 2:
            // Changes between Version 2 and 3
        case currentversion:
            //changes between last change and now
    }
}
```

when you update your database just put a new case with the new Version below this. This way you can maintain every Version of Database and make sure that it will be upgraded properly. Important is, that you don't use a break after each case.

this Code Shows for example one of my Databases, when I increase the Version I simply add a new case for the old Version. When you havent upgraded your Database yet, set the new Version to 1 higher than your old Version and add a case clause for the old Version.

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DATABASE = "Database";
private static int VERSION = 4;


public database(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("CREATE DATABASE TABLE");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    switch(oldVersion){
        case 1:
            db.execSQL("CHANGES DONE AFTER VERSION 1");
        case 2:
            db.execSQL("CHANGES DONE AFTER VERSION 2");
        case 3:
            db.execSQL("CHANGES DONE AFTER VERSION 3");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't delete the database because the users data will be deleted. I'm not sure if `OnUpgrade` will be enough, you mention increasing the database version -  is this necessary when I only want to add a new table?

Comment: Every Change to your Database must be implemented with a Version increase. If you have Version 1 at the Moment, just set the Version to 2 and implement in the onupgrade Funktion a switch for the old Version without a break after each Version, to create a fall through function for later improvements

Comment: Ok so should I add `db.needUpgrade(newVersion);` after creating my new table in `OnUpgrade`?

Comment: updated my answer to clarify how you upgrade database and Keep track of the version

Comment: I don't keep track of the database version, in your edit you added `case 1` etc?

Comment: Every Constructor of a Database Needs an int for the Version. So you already got the track of your Version. If you are using a static int inside your constructor for the Version just increase it by 1. The case 1 is for the case when you upgrade your database from Version 1 to any new Version

Comment: That is what I asked. I have not yet upgraded my database, so that means my database is version 1 currently? So for now I only have to add `case 1:`?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to make changes in tables or create a table on app update, you have to change the version of database. In your case let us suppose you have upgraded from dbversion from 2 to 3 and you want to create a table for versions greater than 2.Then you have to create a table in onUpgrade like below:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(newVersion>=3){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TABLE_NAME` ....");
    }
}
```

here I am creating the table for all the versions greater than 2 since there is a possibility that dbversion gets upgraded from 2 to 4 or some other version greater than 3.

Comment: I don't keep track of my database versions, so can I call `if(newVersion > oldVersion)`?

Comment: yeah in your case that can be used. No need of tracking the database version, you will have to provide the database version to SqliteOpenHelper when you create database, you should just increase the version whenever you want to make changes in tables.

Comment: Ok since I haven't upgraded the database, it should then be version 1 right?

Comment: yeah, you have to keep increasing the version and add code related to changes in tables in onUpgraded. You can also use room library as orm which will be useful for you to handle the tables easily as it converts tables to objects.